# Rails / Devise - Separate authentication for each room

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am writing an application that holds multiple "rooms" for users to join. Each room's user session should be independent from each other.

For example, a user should be able to visit `/room/1` and sign in as `user1`, and visit `/room/2` and sign in as `user2` without signing out from `user1` in `/room/1`. Signing in/out a room should not not affect sessions in other rooms.

Can this be done in Devise? If not, what are the possible options to implement this behavior?

I have read about Devise scopes, however it seems like Devise's scopes need to be predefined and separated into different models, which is impossible in this case (rooms can be created in runtime).

**EDIT:**

To clear things up, I don't need to keep track of users' online or offline status - Traditional cookie-based session is enough, it just needed to be scoped on each individual room.

If I need to implement this from scratch, I will store each room's session cookie in a different cookie. I am just asking if there are existing gems capable of achieving this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should instead just imagine a separate system for this feature that co-exists with Devise or whatever authentication system you choose to use. Not everything should be jammed into your authentication system.

The authentication system will be in charge of the user signing into the application and keeping track of the credentials while a simple join table between the users table and the chat rooms keeps track of the users that are in (or were in) a room.

```
# This is the actual user that signs into your application
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :room_users
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_users
end

# this is just a member of a chat room
# rails g model room_user nickname:string user:belongs_to room:belongs_to left_at:date_time 
class RoomUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user

  def soft_delete
    update_attribute(:left_at, Time.current)
  end
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :room_users
end
```

```
class RoomUsersController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_room!

  # Joining a room
  # POST /rooms/1/room_users
  def create
    @room_user = @room.room_users.new(room_user_params) do |ru|
      ru.user = current_user
    end
    if @room_user.save
      render json: @room_user,
             status: :created
    else 
      render json: { errors: @room_user.errors.full_messages },
             status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # Leaving a room
  # DELETE /room_users/1
  def destroy
    @room_user = @room.room_users.find_by!(user_id: current_user.id)
    @room_user.soft_delete
    head :no_content
  end

  private

  def set_room
    @room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
  end

  def room_user_params
     params.require(:room_user)
           .permit(:nickname)
  end
end
```

> Can this be done in Devise?

Yes and no. Rails (and Devise by extension) by default uses cookie based session storage. That means there is no way to keep track of what users are signed at at any given time since that information is held by the client.

If you want to implement that you would need to switch the session storage to a database store or something like memcached/redis.

A better question is: Should this be done in Devise? I would argue that the answer is no as its already doing a crazy amount of stuff and is quite complex.

Comment: The naming here is pretty awkward and wonky - it's a result of trying to avoid terms like "session" which are already overloaded with meaning. This is only intended as a rough sketchy to show the high level idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However this seems a little bit overcomplicated for me, since I don't need to keep track of online/offline status. I've edited my question, hope it cleared things up.

Comment: I don't think this is really more complicated and you can just swap this out for a storage based on cookies, memcached etc if you want to. As you already have written Devise doesn't do scopes dynamically and I think your chances of finding an existing gem that does exactly what you want here and is maintained is pretty slim.